# Find the maximal interval of existence without actually solving the ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^{\prime}=-\frac{4}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x} y+y^{2}, y(1)=1$$

This is a Ricatti equation, $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ so it's locally Lipschitz and thus there exists a unique solution to the IVP above, $y_p = \pm \frac{2}{x}$ is a particular solution, we can go ahead and solve it using the change of variable $y = y_p +u$ but is there a way to find the maximal interval of existence without actually doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform and combine
$$
x(xy)'=(xy)^2-4.
$$
As the initial point is between the stationary solutions $xy(x)=\pm 2$, the solution exists for the full interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Pardon me, why $(0, \infty)$ and not $(-\infty,0)$ ?

Comment: Because the initial condition is at $x=1$.